# Not sure why this generates a mypy "Incompatible types in assignment"

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, mypy

Simple example of what's confusing me:

```
from typing import Callable, List, Union

Value = Union[bool, int, str]
Helper = Callable[[Value], List[Value]]


def func_with_alias(aa: Value) -> List[Value]:
    return []


def func_with_type(aa: bool) -> List[Value]:
    return []


your_func1: Helper = func_with_alias
your_func2: Helper = func_with_type
```

mypy complains that "your_func2" has an incompatible type:
`error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Callable[[bool], List[Union[bool, int, str]]]", variable has type "Callable[[Union[bool, int, str]], List[Union[bool, int, str]]]")`

Why doesn't it let me do this, as `bool` is in `Union[bool, int, str]`?

```
❯ mypy --version
mypy 0.782
```

Comment: Because it doesn't accept the other two parts of the union. Why *would* that be allowed?

Comment: hmm, so i'm looking at it backwards? I'm thinking it's allowed to take bool, int, or str. But it really means it has to accept any of bool, int or str?

Comment: You've said that a Helper can be called with either a Boolean, an integer or a string. func_with_type can *only* be called with a Boolean, so it's *not* a Helper.

Comment: thanks, Jon. Makes sense. What I am actually doing is building a dispatch dict that has a key of the actual class (say bool, int, or str) and a value of a function that handles it. The return is a list of Value (eg, bool, int, or str). I suppose I need to make the Union a Union of Callables, not a Callable of Unions

Comment: can you post as a reply and i can mark it as answered. thanks for your lightning reply! saved me going insane :)

Comment: please fix the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at what you're saying with your type definitions:

```py
Value = Union[bool, int, str]
```

> A Value can be either a boolean, an integer or a string.

```py
Helper = Callable[[Value], List[Value]]
```

> A Helper takes a Value and returns a List of Values.

Now the assignment that errors:

```py
def func_with_type(aa: bool) -> List[Value]:
    return []

your_func2: Helper = func_with_type
```

`func_with_type` only accepts a boolean, but you're assigning it to a type that should be able to accept an integer or string as well.

---

To see why that doesn't make sense, think about the following *consumer* of a `Helper` function:

```py
def consumer(func: Helper) -> List[Value]:
     return func("Hello, world!")
```

A `Helper` can take a `Value`, which can either be `bool`, `int` or `str`, so this usage should be fine. But `func_with_type` only accepts a `bool`, so cannot be called in this way, therefore we can't consider it a `Helper`.

---

> What I am actually doing is building a dispatch dict that has a key of
> the actual class (say bool, int, or str) and a value of a function
> that handles it. The return is a list of Value (eg, bool, int, or
> str).

Possibly what you want is a [*generic*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) function, where the generic type is constrained by the union:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bool, int, str)
Helper = Callable[[T], List[T]]
```

Comment: thanks again, Jon. I didn't realise I was thinking about this the wrong way. Makes a lot of sense. I ended up with this sort of thing, which works and makes sense but is a bit verbose

`HelperOverride = Callable[[Override], List[Step]]
HelperRuntimeCheck = Callable[[RuntimeCheck], List[Step]]
HelperCommand = Callable[[Command], List[Step]]
Helper = Union[HelperOverride, HelperRuntimeCheck, HelperCommand]`

generic might be the way to go. thanks again!